# Сборка кода в g++ под windows

Tags: windows, g++, c++

Кто собирает программы под виндовым g++? Как достать функцию lseek64? она хоть и прописана в  io.h , но нифига не находится.  error: `lseek64' undeclared (first use this function).

Так же я не могу использовать struct stat64; При попытке создать функцию которая возвращает эту структуру появляются ошибки: error: return type `struct stat64' is incomplete. error: aggregate`stat64 st' has incomplete type and cannot be defined.

И есть ли дефайн, по которому можно определить, что g++ запущен в винде?

Comment: Дефайн есть.

     touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h

      will show all the predefined macros.

Comment: А unistd.h  включен?

Comment: Дефайн WIN32, 

да \#include <unistd.h> 

для результата и смещения в программе используйте long long

Comment: Дефайны WIN32 и _WIN32 не видятся. У меня стоит mingw. #include <unistd.h> есть. Поделитесь проектом в котором это все работает.

Comment: Проект, в котором это все работает: Linux

Comment: Каким проектом?

     #include <stdio.h>
     int main() {
       printf("Hello, World! %d\n", WIN32);
       return 0;
     }

печатает 

     Hello, World! 1

     alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version
     i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 4.6.3

А дальше: что у Вас установлено, как, работает ли эта программа :) ?

@mikillskegg и что, Вы свои программы под linux'ом транслируете/собираете преимущественно под винды/wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@mikelsv](/users/2575/mikelsv), у меня в Windows-7 MinGW

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main ()
{
#ifdef WIN32
  puts("win");
#endif  
  long long rc = lseek64(0,(long long)100,SEEK_CUR);
  printf ("rc = %lld\n",rc);
}
```

запуск

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ g++ t1.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ ./a
win
rc = 100
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ gcc t1.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ ./a
win
rc = 100
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/tst $
```

Comment: Заработало. Но теперь затык на функции getaddrinfo(). Подключал #include "ws2tcpip.h", никакого результата. Даже если прописать ее объявление, ее не находит ld. Ws2_32.lib подключаю.

Comment: @mikelsv у Вас очень интересный компилятор. У себя я такого сообщения -- "затык" -- ни разу не встречал.

Comment: @mikelsv, у меня ее тоже нет. В .h есть текст

    #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
      ....

думаю у меня версия тоже не та. 

А зачем Вам вообще винда-то нужна?

Comment: Подозреваю единственный вариант, напрямую вытащить getaddrinfo() из dll.

В Makefile можно как-то определить, что он запущен в mingw-make? Пробовал ifdef WIN32, но это не сработало.

Раз есть возможность собирать программу в винде, то хочется этой возможностью воспользоваться. Собрать в g++. В MSVS собирается без проблем.

Comment: @mikelsv, я для различения винда/\*nix в Makefile использую

    ifdef _
    # *nix
    PWD  =  pwd
    DEL  =  rm -f
    NULL = /dev/null
    ....
    else
    # win
    PWD  = cd
    DEL  =  del /f
    NULL = nul
    ....
    endif

в начале файла.

Comment: @alexlz, я тоже. Думаю их можно просто удалить.

Comment: @avp комментарий убрал от греха подальше.